# Summation of variables in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using the following class template in multiprocessing:

```
class MyClass
   def __init__(self):
      self.some_counter = 0
   def use_this_class(self, input):
      if some_function(input):
         self.some_counter += 1
```

Since each process receives other `input` variables, the value of `self.some_counter` is different for different processes. When I print it during execution, I can see the prints of all processes, something like:

```
6
7
8
4
5
6
9
10
```

I would like to sum the value of `self.some_counter` between processes before printing. I prefer not to using a global variable that is shared between processes since it will probably increase the execution time. Instead, I would like to sum the values once every N (very large) number of calling of `self.use_this_class`.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at using a Value or a Manager? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Just to clarify, I know you said you didn't want a shared value, but I don't really see any way around it to do what you want unless you use to file system to store your "global" variable but that will likely be slower or you chunk your processes (so only run N processes in a go, sum the values, then start the next N) which would also likely be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't look like it will be possible to implement Value or Manager, since my class is a part of a large code structure and I don't want to open new processes just for it. The processes are already opened by the workers of torch.utils.data.DataLoader and each one has an instance of my class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use shared memory or a *managed* object nor do you need to use a global variable (which cannot be shared between processes, anyway). In fact, I wouldn't bother with a class `MyClass` at all since no state will be retained. Just use a simple function that returns either 0 or 1 depending on what `some_function` returns and then sum up all the resulting values. For example,

```py
def some_function(x):
    return x % 2

def worker(x):
    return 1 if some_function(x) else 0

# Required for Windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    pool = Pool()
    print(sum(pool.map(worker, range(20))), 'calls to some_function returned True')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```None
10 calls to some_function returned True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry for not being clear enough. My multiprocessing configuration is such that `MyClass` is a part of a `torch.utils.data.dataset` object which is a part of `torch.utils.data.dataloader` defined with `num_workers>1`. Not sure how to implement you suggestion in this case.

Comment: @yliats This is one reason you are supposed to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is, so people have a *complete* understanding of what you are trying to do and not go off in the wrong direction. Update your question to show how `MyClass` is used in context.